# Any one aware about QNA maker CORS settings?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I want to set Specific domains in Azure Qna maker app cors settings, not *. Can any one let me know what is the required domains for that, as i do not find any documentation regarding this online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your QnA Maker resource, you are creating an Application (web app) in order to host your endpoint for queries:

[image: QnA Maker creation]

This is due to the architecture which is the following:

[image: QnA Architecture]

So if you want to implement specific CORS rules, go the your Web App and set CORS rules in the dedicated tab:

[image: Cors setup]

---

Additional edit:

Based on the comments (thanks @sumit sharma), the necessary domains are:

- qnamaker-service.trafficmanager.net
- qnamaker.ai

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I need the domain or website name which I can put here ( which may be QNA maker is using internally, I guess here it will be qnamaker.ai ) ? :@nicolas-r

Comment: For which use? What will consume your QnA Maker?

Comment: My Bot which is using bot framework sdk. I already tried putting my bot URL there in QNA maker, but it needs some more domains to be allowrd. @Nicolas-r

Comment: @sumitsharma Did you ever get this resolved? I'm being requested to add specific domains in CORS but I'm concerned that I will be breaking my bot.

Comment: @billoverton Yes, you need to put those 2 domains in **CORS settings** and you are good to go. https://qnamaker-service.trafficmanager.net and https://www.qnamaker.ai

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Nicholas R gives you everything you need to solve this issue except the domains to add (tried to edit by edit queue is full). If you are looking for the domains to add here, it should be at a minimum https://qnamaker-service.trafficmanager.net and https://www.qnamaker.ai. I added these and have not had any issues with the service since removing "allow all".

Comment: Thanks, I have added these items in my reply